# How is this error possible and what can be done about it? "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I'm using Python 3 with the pandas library and some other data science libraries. After running into a variety of subtle type errors while just trying to compare values across two columns that should contain like integer values in a single pandas DataFrame (although the Python interpreter arbitrarily interprets the types as float, string, or series, seemingly almost at random), I'm now running into this inexplicable / nonsensical seeming error while attempting to cast back to integer, after converting the values to string to strip out blank spaces introduced (presumably by pandas internal processing, because my code tries to keep the type int throughout) much further upstream in the program flow.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'

The main problem I have with this error message is there should be no reason a type conversion to int should ever blow up on the value '1.0.' Just taking the error message at face value, it makes no sense to me and seems like a deeper problem or bug in pandas.

But ignoring more fundamental problems or bugs in Python or pandas, any help resolving this in a generalizable way that will play nice consistently in every reasonable scenario (behaving more like strongly-typed, type-safe code, basically) would be appreciated.

Here's the bit of code where I'm trying to deal with all the various type conversion and blank value issues I've bumped into at once, because I've gone round and around on this a few times in subtly different scenarios, and every time I thought I'd finally bullet-proofed this bit of code and gotten it working as intended in every case, some new unexpected type conversion issue like this crops up.

```
df[getVariableLabel(outvar)] = df[getVariableLabel(outvar)].astype(str).str.strip()
df['prediction'] = df['prediction'].astype(str).str.strip()

actual = np.array(df[getVariableLabel(outvar)].fillna(-1).astype(int))

// this is the specific line that throws the error
predicted = np.array(df['prediction'].fillna(-1).astype(int))
```

For further context on the code above, the "df" object is a pandas dataframe passed in by parameter. "getVariableLabel" is a helper function used to format a dynamic field name. Both columns contain simple "1" and "0" values, except where there may be nAn/blanks (which I'm attempting to fill with dummy values).

It doesn't really have to be a conversion to int for my needs. String values would be fine, too, if it were possible to keep pandas/Python from arbitrarily treating one series as ints, and the other, as floats before the conversion to string, which makes value comparisons between the two sets of values fail.

Here's the bit of the call stack dump where pandas is throwing the error, for further context:

> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
>   line 874, in astype_nansafe
>       return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
>
> File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 560, in
>   pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for myself with the following substitution, in case anyone else runs into this. It may also have helped that I updated pandas from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2, since that update did includes some type conversion bug fixes, but more likely it was this workaround (where pd is of course the alias for the pandas library):

```
df[getVariableLabel(outvar)] = pd.to_numeric(df[getVariableLabel(outvar)])
df['prediction'] = pd.to_numeric(df['prediction'])
```

The original value error message is still confusing and seems like a bug but this worked in my particular case.